# Differences in Mobile and Desktop Application Testing

Tags: testing

How would you test a ‘Mobile’ version of IM?   What are some key differences between testing this version versus a desktop application?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to account for unstable connectivity - the program should be ready to deal with temporary and permanent network coverage losses.

Resources consumption (memory footprint, network bandwidth and CPU time) is also to be considered. Noone wants a program that drains the battery in an hour, occupies all memory or causes a giant bill to the owner.

Answer (score 0):

Both memory requirement and network bandwidth has to be kept to as low as possible...

Answer (score 0):

adding to sharptooth's answer, notifications on sending/receiving a message. Support for voice chat/video chat via available hardware :)